# react error .. what is "DrawerLayoutAndroid"?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/components/GestureComponents.web.js 27:55-76
export 'DrawerLayoutAndroid' (imported as 'RNDrawerLayoutAndroid') was not found in 'react-native' (possible exports: AccessibilityInfo, ActivityIndicator, Alert, Animated, AppRegistry, AppState, Appearance, BackHandler, Button, CheckBox, Clipboard, DeviceEventEmitter, Dimensions, Easing, FlatList, I18nManager, Image, ImageBackground, InteractionManager, Keyboard, KeyboardAvoidingView, LayoutAnimation, Linking, LogBox, Modal, NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules, PanResponder, Picker, PixelRatio, Platform, Pressable,
ProgressBar, RefreshControl, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, SectionList, Share, StatusBar, StyleSheet, Switch, Text, TextInput, Touchable, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableWithoutFeedback, UIManager, Vibration, View, VirtualizedList, YellowBox, findNodeHandle, processColor, render, unmountComponentAtNode, unstable_createElement, useColorScheme, useLocale
useLocaleContext, useWindowDimensions)

ERROR in ./node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/lib/module/components/GestureComponents.web.js 31:32-63
export 'DrawerLayoutAndroid' (imported as 'RNDrawerLayoutAndroid') was not found in 'react-native' (possible exports: AccessibilitessibilityInfo, ActivityIndicator, Alert, Animated, AppRegistry, AppState, Appearance, BackHandler, Button, CheckBox, ClieviceEvenpboard, DeviceEventEmitter, Dimensions, Easing, FlatList, I18nManager, Image, ImageBackground, InteractionManager, KeyboangView, Lrd, KeyboardAvoidingView, LayoutAnimation, Linking, LogBox, Modal, NativeEventEmitter, NativeModules, PanResponder, Pickeessable, r, PixelRatio, Platform, Pressable, ProgressBar, RefreshControl, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, SectionList, Share, StatusBar,, Touchab StyleSheet, Switch, Text, TextInput, Touchable, TouchableHighlight, TouchableNativeFeedback, TouchableOpacity, TouchableVirtualizWithoutFeedback, UIManager, Vibration, View, VirtualizedList, YellowBox, findNodeHandle, processColor, render, unmountComuseLocaleponentAtNode, unstable_createElement, useColorScheme, useLocaleContext, useWindowDimensions)

here is my errors what should I do? I already have been delete all node_modules folder and reinstall
I don't know what to do ..
this errors have been occuar after I do "npm audit fix --force" in my terminal

I want to display my project without any error

Comment: Is this react or react native error?

Comment: i think it's react-native error 
is there any difference if it is react error? or react-native error?

Comment: I think, the package react-native-gesture, only works in the react native, not in react web

Comment: thank you for your advice! I deleted every module relative with react-native and It works!!